# WSDL как описать тэг, который имеет и атрибут и строковое значение?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Можно описать такую структуру:

```
<element name="One" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="Two" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

И это превратится в такой `xml`:

```
<One>
  <Two>строка</Two>
  <Two>ещё строка</Two>
</One>
```

А можно описать такую структуру:

```
<element name="One" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="Two" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <complexType>
          <attribute name="MyAttr" type="string" />
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

И это превратится в такой `xml`:

```
<One>
  <Two MyAttr="строка" />
  <Two MyAttr="ещё строка" />
</One>
```

Но как мне в `wsdl` описать структуру, которая превратится в:

```
<One>
  <Two MyAttr="строка 1">строка 2</Two>
  <Two MyAttr="строка 3">строка 4</Two>
</One>
```

???

P.S. И какую структуру данных мне нужно будет скормить soap серверу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
<element name="One">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="Two" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <complexType>
          <simpleContent>
            <extension base="string">
              <attribute name="MyAttr" type="string" />
            </extension>
          </simpleContent>
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Структура данных должна быть: класс One, содержащий коллекцию классов Two.

Comment: по схеме понятно, спасибо!

Comment: Я не понимаю, как должен выглядеть класс Two. У него должно быть поле/ключ MyAttr, и это значение попадет в атрибут MyAttr. Но по какому ключу по должно лежать значение, которое попадет в "тело" тэга?

Comment: @muturgan - я не знаю php, поэтому не смогу помочь с этим

Comment: А как бы вы это сделали на знакомом языке? )) Возможно "транспиляция" будет довольно предсказуемой.

Comment: Прелесть ситуации в том, что я тоже не знаю пхп))

Comment: Тогда, наверное, следует задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: В процессе.....